# Installing MacPorts on MountainLion with this command: sudo port install libusb +universal

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, macports, libusb

I'm trying to install MacPorts on MountainLion using this command:

> sudo port install libusb +universal

I'm getting this error:

> org.macports.extract for port libusb returned: command execution failed

and this:

> Processing of port libusb failed

Here is main.log

```
version:1
:debug:main libusb has no conflicts
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (libusb)
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 505
:debug:archivefetch archivefetch phase started at Wed Apr 23 16:33:35 EDT 2014
:msg:archivefetch --->  Fetching archive for libusb
:debug:archivefetch Executing org.macports.archivefetch (libusb)
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 0/0
:debug:archivefetch chowned /opt/local/var/macports/incoming to macports
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 505/501
:info:archivefetch --->  libusb-1.0.18_0+universal.darwin_12.i386-x86_64.tbz2 doesn't seem to exist in /opt/local/var/macports/incoming/verified
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch libusb-1.0.18_0+universal.darwin_12.i386-x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libusb
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed:: The requested URL returned error: 404
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch libusb-1.0.18_0+universal.darwin_12.i386-x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/libusb
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed:: The requested URL returned error: 404
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch libusb-1.0.18_0+universal.darwin_12.i386-x86_64.tbz2 from http://nue.de.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/libusb
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed:: The requested URL returned error: 404
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:fetch fetch phase started at Wed Apr 23 16:33:36 EDT 2014
:notice:fetch --->  Fetching distfiles for libusb
:debug:fetch Can't run fetch on this port without elevated privileges. Escalating privileges back to root.
:debug:fetch euid changed to: 0. egid changed to: 0.
:debug:fetch changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:fetch egid changed to: 501
:debug:fetch euid changed to: 505
:debug:fetch Executing org.macports.fetch (libusb)
:info:fetch --->  libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2 doesn't seem to exist in /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libusb
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2 from http://superb-dca2.dl.sourceforge.net/libusb
:debug:fetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:checksum checksum phase started at Wed Apr 23 16:33:42 EDT 2014
:notice:checksum --->  Verifying checksums for libusb
:debug:checksum Executing org.macports.checksum (libusb)
:info:checksum --->  Checksumming libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2
:debug:checksum Correct (rmd160) checksum for libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2
:debug:checksum Correct (sha256) checksum for libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2
:debug:checksum Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:extract extract phase started at Wed Apr 23 16:33:42 EDT 2014
:notice:extract --->  Extracting libusb
:debug:extract setting option extract.cmd to /usr/bin/bzip2
:debug:extract Executing org.macports.extract (libusb)
:info:extract --->  Extracting libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2
:debug:extract setting option extract.args to '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libusb/libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2'
:debug:extract Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_private_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libusb/libusb/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.8'
:debug:extract Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_private_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libusb/libusb/work" && /usr/bin/bzip2 -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libusb/libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf -'
:debug:extract Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_private_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libusb/libusb/work" && /usr/bin/bzip2 -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libusb/libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf - 
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18: Cannot mkdir: Operation not permitted
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/doc: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/doc/doxygen.cfg.in: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/doc/Makefile.in: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/doc/Makefile.am: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/configure: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/aclocal.m4: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/configure.ac: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/COPYING: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/config.sub: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/TODO: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/install-sh: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Makefile.in: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/tests: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/tests/libusb_testlib.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/tests/Makefile.in: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/tests/stress.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/tests/Makefile.am: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/tests/testlib.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/README: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/depcomp: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/compile: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/ChangeLog: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/missing: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb-1.0.pc.in: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/ltmain.sh: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/config.guess: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Makefile.am: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/AUTHORS: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/io.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/hotplug.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/libusb-1.0.rc: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/libusbi.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/libusb.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/sync.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/Makefile.in: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/libusb-1.0.def: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/strerror.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/threads_windows.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/poll_posix.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/windows_usb.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/windows_usb.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/poll_windows.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/darwin_usb.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/openbsd_usb.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/linux_usbfs.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/darwin_usb.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/linux_usbfs.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/wince_usb.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/wince_usb.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/threads_windows.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/linux_udev.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/windows_common.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/poll_posix.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/netbsd_usb.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/threads_posix.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/poll_windows.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/linux_netlink.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/os/threads_posix.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/version_nano.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/descriptor.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/Makefile.am: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/version.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/hotplug.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/libusb/core.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/config.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/debug.xcconfig: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/libusb.xcconfig: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/libusb_debug.xcconfig: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/common.xcconfig: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/libusb.xcodeproj: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/libusb.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/libusb_release.xcconfig: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/Xcode/release.xcconfig: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android/config.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android/jni: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android/jni/Android.mk: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android/jni/libusb.mk: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android/jni/examples.mk: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android/jni/Application.mk: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android/jni/tests.mk: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/android/README: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/INSTALL: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/config.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_static.dsp: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb_2010.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_dll_2005.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/fxload_2010.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb.dsw: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs_2012.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/getopt_2012.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/getopt_2013.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/missing.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb_2012.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/hotplugtest_sources: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_wince.sln: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/hotplugtest_2010.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_dll_2010.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/fxload_2012.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/stress_wince.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/fxload_2012.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_dll_2012.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/getopt_2005.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_dll_wince.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_static_wince.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs.dsp: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_dll_2012.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/stress_2012.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb_2010.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs_sources: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_static_2012.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_2005.sln: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_dll.dsp: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/stress_2010.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs_2012.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs_wince.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/getopt_sources: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_2010.sln: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs_2005.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs_2010.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_dll_2013.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs_2010.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/hotplugtest_2012.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/fxload_sources: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/stress_2012.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb_2012.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/stress_2013.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb_sources: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb.dsp: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/fxload_2010.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_sources: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_2012.sln: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/hotplugtest_2013.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/listdevs_2013.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/errno.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_static_2010.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/getopt_2010.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/stdint.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/getopt_2010.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/getopt_2012.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb_wince.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/inttypes.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_static_2010.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb_2005.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_static_2005.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/fxload_2013.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_dll_2010.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_static_2013.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/stress_2005.vcproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/ddk_build.cmd: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_2013.sln: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/missing.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/stress_2010.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/hotplugtest_2010.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/libusb_static_2012.vcxproj.filters: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/hotplugtest_2012.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/msvc/xusb_2013.vcxproj: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/PORTING: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/config.h.in: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/NEWS: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/ezusb.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/dpfp.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/dpfp_threaded.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/listdevs.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/getopt: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/getopt/getopt.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/getopt/getopt.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/getopt/getopt1.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/hotplugtest.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/ezusb.h: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/Makefile.in: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/sam3u_benchmark.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/fxload.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/Makefile.am: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: libusb-1.0.18/examples/xusb.c: Cannot open: No such file or directory
:info:extract /usr/bin/gnutar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
:info:extract Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_private_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libusb/libusb/work" && /usr/bin/bzip2 -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libusb/libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf - 
:info:extract Exit code: 2
:error:extract org.macports.extract for port libusb returned: command execution failed
:debug:extract Error code: NONE
:debug:extract Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:extract Warning: targets not executed for libusb: org.macports.activate org.macports.extract org.macports.patch org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:extract Please see the log file for port libusb for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_private_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libusb/libusb/main.log
```

Comment: looks like some of your earliest problems in your log are "`404`" errors from the server. ["`404`" means "Not Found"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).  I wonder if the "`libusb-1.0.18_0+universal.darwin_12.i386-x86_64.tbz2`" file has disappeared from MacPorts?

Comment: Try to force a binary-only install: `port -b install libusb [-universal]`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was [reported to the MacPorts project](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/43465) and we were able to deduce that the problem was that /opt was a symlink, and that this had been caused by installing an ancient version of the Cisco VPN client. The solution was to make /opt a normal directory again. MacPorts 2.2 had a problem handling portions of the prefix being a symlink; [this problem](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/39850) was fixed in MacPorts 2.3.